# WPF ListView убрать подсветку

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Доброго дня, знатоки! Столкнулся с такой проблемой, необходимо сделать выделение списка ListView прозрачным, чтобы оно вообще никак не фигурировало.

```
<Style.Resources>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
</Style.Resources>
```

Мой вариант делает все, как нужно но, если после клика на объект, кликнуть в любое другое место формы, объект снова подсвечивается, только белым. Как обойти эту проблему?

Comment: настроить Trigger для события клика мыши

Comment: @Bulson, может быть у Вас есть пример для такого случая?

Comment: про триггеры уже были вопросы, на сайте есть поиск...

Comment: А почему бы вам просто не использовать `ItemsControl` вместо `ListView`?

Comment: @VladD я уже сам запутался, что мне проще (( Много чего перепробовал и перечитал

Comment: Окей, а ItemsControl пробовали?

Comment: @VladD еще нет, сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: не совсем понятно что вы хотите получить в итоге

Comment: А если просто установить `SelectedItem = null`?

Comment: @Андрей, не дает результат(

Comment: @SyntaxWEB6stPRODWowSuite, как именно пробовали? Подпишитесь на событие `SelectionChanged` и в нем устанавливайте `SelectedItem = null`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы по каким-то причинам не хотите использовать `ItemsControl` (ну, например, потому что в `ListView` с помощью представления `GridView` можно быстро и просто вывести данные в красивой таблице), то можете просто "вручную" снять выделение с элемента при его установке:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyListView.SelectionChanged += (s, e) => MyListView.SelectedItem = null;
}
```